# What is a.e. a.s

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am reading a paper which uses almost everywhere almost surely (a.e.,a.s.) simultaneously, I am not quite sure what it means then. To be specific, they consider  a stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ such that $|X_t| < +\infty$ a.e., a.s. Does it mean for all $t$, almost surely $\omega \in \Omega$? Why do they need the a.e. in that case?

Comment: With probability $1$, $|X_t| < +\infty$ for almost every $t$ (i.e. except for a set of $t$'s of Lebesgue measure $0$ that depends on $\omega$).

Comment: so it's not the same as $P(|X_t|< + \infty, \text{ for all } t \in [0, +\infty))=1$?

Comment: No.  For that, they wouldn't use the "a.e.".